# Add the JavaFX UI Custom controls to Scene Builder

Tags: java, javafx, custom-controls, scenebuilder

I have been following the wise advice from [Hendrick](http://www.guigarage.com/2012/11/custom-ui-controls-with-javafx-part-1/) and [Harmonic code](http://harmoniccode.blogspot.com/) to create my UI Controls in JavaFX. I like so much the organization of the Control, Skin+Behavior and CSS styling. The unique disadvantage of using this approach is that i don't know how to use Scene Builder directly to build my GUI with my Controls(At least i don't know how can i do that). So, that is my question:

There is some way to import my JavaFX UI Controls to Scene Builder software?

This could help me to save much time.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I can admit that there is unclear documentation about creating custom controls that will be fully compatible with scene builder.

ControlsFX developers team also have problems with proper third party controls creation to satisfy Scene Builder.

I created issue on jira of Scene Builder about that lack of information -> https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/DTL-6909

Also you can read more about how and what problems you can meet on loading process of custom controls to Scene Builder here -> https://bitbucket.org/controlsfx/controlsfx/issue/243/all-controls-should-be-supported-by

Also you can display Scene Builder's analysis of your loaded third party controls (e.g.):
[image: Scene Builder Analysis]
[image: Scene Builder Analysis result]

Comment: That is so sad man. I've been thinking if it was not a good idea to make my ui controls with this approach. Maybe i just have to move on and make my controllers with FXML. PD: Maye the idea of put a container in the FXML GUI is not bad...

Comment: @multiplayer1080 it depends what kind of control do you want to create. If   some kind of container i.e. form that you will be using in many places then the best way will be to create control using FXML and controller. But if your control is some totally custom like new button with wird shape and behaviors then better will be create new jar with "Control, Skin+Behavior and CSS styling". Only then you just need to remember to create the correct code that Scene Builder will understand. This it is not feasible because all standard controls are working properly with Scene Builder somehow.

Comment: Actually i have created a gauge, a led bar and other controls like those. I am following the same way to create them as Hendrick and Gerrit (links above in the question) and i have nothing but errors when i try to import them to in Scene Builder.

Comment: @multiplayer1080 read comments from ControlsFX topic (I posted link in my answer). Use some of Andreas Liebelt advices and rework you code to meet this requirements. Try also contact to Hendrick and/or Gerrit, maybe they will help you with that code to make it compatible with Scene Builder. Also read this http://www.b4x.com/b4j/help/jfxtrasgauges.html

Comment: So. There is a reliable solution?  I've been reading the article but can't find the right direction to solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can use both a FXML or a jar and load it into the SceneBuilder, independent of the Project. You can create Templates and load them into the SceneBuilder to reuse them in many Projects.

Look at the right side of the Library-Searchbar in the Top-Left Corner. If you click on that gear-wheel you will see the Menupoint - "Import JAR/FXML File".

Answer (score 0):

You can use  [this tutorial](http://code.makery.ch/java/javafx-8-tutorial-part1/)

There described JavaFX and Scene Builer, CSS, Ant, MVC pattern